# What may cause massive data loss and how to further investigate it

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

We have been working with Firebird for a long time now, recently we´ve just upgraded from 2.0 to 2.5 without any problem.
Our product is deployed in 500+ customers and is very stable.

The problem is that we´ve encountered a very odd problem in one of our customers, three different databases, each one hosted in different servers, presented a similar problem: massive data loss. This has happened in different dates, with no apparent relation to each other, even after the upgrade from 2.0 to 2.5. The customer said that there were no power shortages what so ever.

Most of the tables suddenly got empty, gfix didn´t work for these cases, it didn´t even show an error when trying to validate. The database itself was still accessible, it did not go corrupt, but the tables were empty. Also, some triggers were missing/deactivated.

IBSurgeon FirstAid Direct got this:

```
03/12/2014 16:07:51 INFO: Actual PageCount: 17621 found in database 
03/12/2014 16:07:51 ERROR: Found 1103 undefined or unrecognized pages.
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO:  ------------------- Starting diagnose
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: Running procedure: Header page check
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: ODS Major = 11 (32779)
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: ODS Minor = 2
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: Next transaction = 19343161
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: Oldest transaction = 19343157
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: Oldest active = 19343158
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: Oldest snapshot = 19343158
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: PageSize is Ok = 16384
03/12/2014 16:08:51 INFO: Running procedure: Checking of RDB$Pages consistency
03/12/2014 16:08:52 INFO: Checking of RDB$Pages consistency: Ok
03/12/2014 16:09:14 INFO: Low-level check of all relations: Ok
```

My first guess is a disk problem, but it is a difficult to prove argument since it happened in three different servers already.

My question is: **what could cause such problem and how can I verify it accordingly?**

Any help is very welcome, I am not a Firebird expert so I´d appreciate every suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a normal deleting of data (until there are no broken foreign keys), I would say - some mistake in business logic, like DELETE FROM without WHERE.

To investigate it, try to use FirstAID Extractor. On tab "Config" turn on Recovery records - Deleted and Old versions, and check those tables for old and deleted record versions.

Also, don't hesitate to contact us directly :)

Regards,
Alexey Kovyazin

IBSurgeon

Comment: it sure does look like deleted data, the thing is that we don't have any logic that would do that... even the possibility of some malicious employee has been evaluated. I'm gonna give a try with the Extractor, thanks.

Comment: Well I just checked the database as you instructed, when I try to preview the data of the problematic tables I get this kind of message: `[231] 19:36:29.695 Warning> Page 1 of relation 167 (real page #787) has no readable data`. Does this point out to a file corruption? The `Pages` columns of the tables show that there are pages allocated for them...

Comment: No, not a corruption, it means that there  are no data on this page. If it was deleted, and garbage collection happened, it will be impossible to see what data were there. I would suggest to concentrate on preventing further deletes - create after delete and after update triggers to log all deletes and updates into external table.

Comment: I see, what about those missing/deactivated triggers I mentioned on OP, any clues? We've already prepared a logging software that uses the trace API to monitor the operations on the database, in this case we are curious about what and who is causing the data loss